# How to select only complete in a panda data.frame

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataframe

I have the following data-set on python

```
import pandas as pd
bcw = pd.read_csv('http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/breast-cancer-wisconsin.data', header=None)
```

Lines like 24 have missing values:

```
1057013,8,4,5,1,2,?,7,3,1,4
```

On `column 7`, there is a `'?'`, and I want to drop this line. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your specific example in `column: 7`:

```
bcw = bcw[bcw[7] != '?']
```

However, I actually downloaded the dataset and found the same anomaly in `column: 6`, so this code will look through all columns for `'?'` and remove the rows:

```
for col in bcw.columns:
    if bcw[col].dtype != 'int64':
        print "Removing possible '?' in column %s..." % col
        bcw = bcw[bcw[col] != '?']

>>> Removing possible '?' in column 6...
```

Comment: Thank you, i'm starting with python and still struggling with these little things, but that was exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You might try

```
import numpy as np
irow = np.all(np.array(bcw) != '?', axis=1)
bcw = bcw.ix[irow, :]
```

`np.array(bcw) != '?'` results in a Boolean array (I tried compare `bcw` to `'?'` directly but got errors so I convert it to `np.array` first) which indicates the positions where is not `'?'`.

`np.all(xx, axis=1)` convert the 2-dimension Boolean array to 1-dimension, and `axis=1` means row-wise: if and only if all elements in a row is `True`, the corresponding element in the result array is `True`. Now we get an Boolean index array indicating rows containing no `'?'`.

As `irow` is Boolean index array, you can also indexing `bcw` with forms below:

```
bcw.ix[irow]
bcw[irow]
```

But if `irow` is Integer index array instead of Boolean one, the last form will cause an error. I am some confused about pandas data frame indexing so I would be thankful if anyone tells me.